# How to import Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The following code in my project gets the following error.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, 
  IConfiguration configuration, 
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment environment) // Error
{
    //    .....
    return services;
}
```

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I already import the nuget package.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: what version of Core are you using? your package versions seem all over the place. Be sure to reference the package equal to the same version of your core target

Comment: .net core 3.0...

Comment: In the project https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders, the same code exists and there is no error. https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection.cs

Comment: I found that the error is gone after add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="3.0.0" />`.

Comment: Under Dependencies - > Frameworks, verify that Microsoft.AspNetCore. App & Microsoft.NETCore.App is being referred. I checked my project in Visual Studio & found this. Please try this & let me know. I have not used pkg ref mentioned by you & my code works without that

Comment: 1.  "I already import the nuget package." : Note you're referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` of **`2.2`**. However, the `IWebHostEnvironment` is introduced since **`3.0`**.  2. Could you please show us the `*.csproj`?  Because it should be a built-in interface since ASP.NET Core 3.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core 3.1 Get wwwroot Path In Separate Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401079/asp-net-core-3-1-get-wwwroot-path-in-separate-class-library)

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment` in a separate library project other than your web project, you have to explicitly add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package reference to the library project by editing the project file.

In Dotnet 5.0 also, we have to follow same approach.

```
<Project SDK="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>...</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Images of code have all kinds of usability problems; please paste text as text. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The Microsoft documentation calls out that the interface IWebHostEnvironment is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0    - which currently shows as version 2.2.7. - the addition of the FrameworkReference was needed to resolve - and I did see some ideas that it was needed when it was a library using the interface outside of the Web project. (You also do not get intellisense when you add that Framework Reference - it does fix this though).

Answer (score 11):

I've got exactly your problem and know how to fix it :)

Add this to your *.csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So `IWebHostEnvironment` is in the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

I really don't know why `IWebHostEnvironment` doesn't come with the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` even if it is in that namespace. It's really confusing. Maybe this will be cleaned up in the future...

**UPDATE**

The above solution works on Winidows but I've now tried to get this project running on macOS with Visual Studio for Mac and it just could not build. The solution to this was as denoted in the comments by @mindplay.dk to change the project type to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` in the first line of the *.csproj file. (even if this does not make any sense for my ClassLibrary project)

Steps to Reproduce: Just try to put IWebHostEnvironment in a separate classlibrary project and you run into all theses issues...

Comment: Adding this as a package reference gave me a warning (in VS 2019) saying you shouldn't do that. This answer clued me in, but the solution for me, finally, was to change the SDK attribute of the Project root node in the .csproj file to: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` - I learned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2019) why and how that works. (I remain puzzled as to why something so crucial doesn't seem to appear anywhere in VS 2019. It displays the list of *resolved* frameworks, but the SDK setting itself is nowhere to be found)

Comment: Switching the Project/Sdk to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web indeed "works" but this also requires your "class library" to now have a Program.Main()... I get this error when I don't have that: `CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on CodingYourLife's answer.
When including an additional framework you should include it with the `FrameworkReference` tag for it to load correctly:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```