# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Get wwwroot Path In Separate Class Library

Tags: asp.net-core

Previously, I could access `IHostingEnvironment` using DI and pass that into my separate class library to get the wwwroot path, but in 3.1, `IHostingEnvironment` is being deprecated and it's suggested to use `IWebHostEnvironment`.  For the life of me, I can't find a NuGet package to add to gain access to that object.  I've tried `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` with no luck.  Anyone?  If it's no longer possible using this method, can someone propose a solution so that I can map a path to the wwwroot folder for my application?

Comment: So, you just need a way to access the wwwroot path of the asp.net core project in your solution?

Comment: See this documentation: [Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link by poke about seeing the documentation is an answer but since links can die, here is the solution.

As of .NET Core 3.0, projects using the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web MSBuild SDK implicitly reference the shared framework. Projects using the Microsoft.NET.Sdk or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor SDK must reference ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework.

In you project file, add this...

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on John81's answer a bit: The relevant section of the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) state:

> To reference ASP.NET Core, add the following `<FrameworkReference>`
>   element to your project file:
>
> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
>   </PropertyGroup>
>
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
>   </ItemGroup>
>
> </Project>
> ```
>
> Referencing ASP.NET Core in this manner is only supported for projects
>   targeting .NET Core 3.x.

Note the `TargetFramework` is `netcoreapp3.0`, which complies with the statement above that this only works for projects targeting .NET Core 3.x. Most library projects target some version of **netstandard**, so you need to change the `<targetFramework>` element in addition to adding the `<FrameworkReference>`.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation. 
This type is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1).